Netlify api rewrite doesn't seem to work after page reload
I have a Web api on a VPS that I'm pointing to in my _redirects file in Netlify to handle the HTTP requests.
Everything works fine until I reload any page other than the root page, for every other page it tries to make a network call to the actual root that I'm on, but that doesn't even exist because they're client side routes between pages.
So it would try to call my backend api when I'm on any other page and I refresh, even though it's just a route on my frontend side.
ie. myapi.com/faq, or myapi.com/about-us
The api call will fail, and I don't see any content after the refresh.
This is my _redirects file I use to deploy to Netlify.
/* http://myapi.com:8080/:splat 200
/* /index.html 200


Solved it, Had the wrong redirect routing in my file.
It should be
/api/* http://myapi.com:8080/api/:splat 200
/* /index.html 200

instead of
/* http://myapi.com:8080/:splat 200
/* /index.html 200

I can now make requests to my HTTP api from netlify and also refresh pages without getting network errors
